# Is it necessary to use smart contract analysis tools like oyente or slither? What is the proper way to show that my contracts are working fine?

Tags: slither

I have created a few smart contracts as a part of a project and tested the features by writing unit tests, and they work fine. Now do I need slither or other analyzing tool? What are the parameters that decide how good a smart contract is?

Comment: You will never know until someone audits your contracts, and even then there may be some bugs slipping. Generally automated analysis (slither etc..) are good to have but far from fool-proof

Answer (score 0):

You write tests to find bugs in your code but Ethereum audit is not for finding bugs. Ethereum audit is used to find security vulnerabilities in your code. For example, if your contract is vulnerable to reentrancy attack if you run `slither` you will get this warning:

```
Reentrancy in shopContract.withdraw()
    External calls:
    - (success) = msg.sender.call{value: balance}() 
    State variables written after the call(s)
   Reference: https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation#reentrancy-vulnerabilities
```

Once you deploy your code, that code is open to everyone. If hackers find vulnerabilities in your code after you deploy, they can steal money from your contract.

[this website is for ethereum audit](https://secureum.substack.com/)